# Return values as 1 or 0 together with percent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I need a SELECT that will result in a percentage and columns with 1 and 0 for exist or not exist.

The goal is to generate data for a usage meter (Percentage 0.0-1.0) and each measurable value as 1 or 0.
It also has to show a row for every user in a users table, even if that user has no items at all.

Scenario:

- In one table, a user can have many items, thet all have a specific ItemType.

  Like type A, B, C, D or E
- If a user has items in all types, the result should be (5/5 100%):

  Percentage  A  B  C  D  E

  1.0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
- If a user has none of the types (0/5 0%):

  Percentage  A  B  C  D  E

  0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
- If a user has some of the types (3/5 60%):

  Percentage  A  B  C  D  E

  0.6, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0

  SAMPLE:

[image: Sample data and wanted result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE to calculate A,B,C,D and E using CASE or IIF and then calculate final percentatge.

> ```
> ;WITH tbl AS
> (
> SELECT 
>     u.id,
>     u.name,
>     CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM items WHERE user_id = u.id AND itemtype = 'A') 
>          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A],
>     CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM items WHERE user_id = u.id AND itemtype = 'B') 
>          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [B],
>     CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM items WHERE user_id = u.id AND itemtype = 'C') 
>          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [C], 
>     CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM items WHERE user_id = u.id AND itemtype = 'D') 
>          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [D],
>     CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM items WHERE user_id = u.id AND itemtype = 'E') 
>          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [E]
> FROM
>     users u
> )
> SELECT
>     id,
>     name,
>     CAST((A+B+C+D+E) / 5.0 as decimal(10,1)) AS Percentatge,
>     A,
>     B,
>     C,
>     D,
>     E
> FROM
>     tbl;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  | Percentatge |  A |  B |  C |  D |  E
> -: | :---- | :---------- | -: | -: | -: | -: | -:
>  1 | user1 | 1.0         |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1
>  2 | user2 | 0.4         |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0
>  3 | user3 | 0.2         |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0
>  4 | user4 | 0.0         |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0
>  5 | user5 | 0.0         |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=daca1a3af4847e99607cb36a9ca26a42)*

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Pivot operator for this, this should work, it might need some tweaks depending on how much items are expected.

```
CREATE TABLE #users(id int identity(1,1), 
                    Name nvarchar(255));
INSERT into #users(Name)
VALUES('Adam'),('Bart'),('Curt'),('Dan');

CREATE TABLE #items(id int identity(1,1), 
                    User_id int, 
                    ItemType nvarchar(255));

INSERT into #items( User_id,
                    ItemType)
values(1,'Car'),(1,'Bike'),(1,'Truck'),(1,'Motorbike'),(1,'Kickbike'),(2,'Bike'),(2,'Car'),(3,'Bike');

CREATE TABLE #temp ( user_id int,
                     Car tinyint, 
                     Bike tinyint, 
                     Truck tinyint, 
                     Motorbike tinyint, 
                     Kickbike tinyint);

INSERT INTO #temp (user_id , 
                    Car, 
                    Bike, 
                    Truck, 
                    Motorbike, 
                    Kickbike)
SELECT  id,
        Car,
        Bike,
        Truck,
        Motorbike,
        KickBike 
FROM ( 
        SELECT  u.id as id,
                ItemType, 
                count(ItemType) as items 
        FROM #users u
        LEFT JOIN #items i on u.id = i.User_id
        GROUP by u.id,ItemType
    ) as s
PIVOT
    (
    count(items) for ItemType IN (Car,Bike,Truck,Motorbike,KickBike)
    ) as pvt;



SELECT  User_id, 
        (Car + Bike + Truck + Motorbike + Kickbike)/ 5.0 as percentage,
        Car,
        Bike,
        Truck, 
        Motorbike, 
        Kickbike 
FROM #temp;

DROP TABLE #items;
DROP TABLE #users;
DROP TABLE #temp;
```